# I need help in understanding Port vs protocol

Tags: html, web, port

my question as follows   Why do we need port when there’s protocol ,- that’s exactly defining what  are the terms of transferring or receiving data

Did not actually get it, i am new to web processes:)

Comment: protocol and port are two different concepts. There are certain ports that are "reserved" for certain protocols, but that's by convention (and documented in RFCs) and convenience, for example, HTTPS over TCP port 443. But you could run HTTPS over any TCP port, and for that matter run something else over TCP port 443.

Comment: But for example i am building server why do i need to define which port to listen to if for example the protocol already defined the data it means its logical what and where afterwards its supposed to go

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is  the process , algorithm between receive and response , client-server, how URL request is transferred to server? Suppose there i can get why we need to have port…

Answer (score 0):

**A protocol is a specification for how two devices should exchange data in a way that they can both understand. A port is kind of a numbered 'tag' that helps a computer decide who should receive an incoming piece of data.**

Many protocols have a port that they run on by default; this makes it easier to discover them or configure applications that use them. But that's not a hard rule; they could always listen on a different port, as long as anyone contacting them knew about the change.

A protocol is an agreement on how to interpret data and how to respond to messages. They generally specify message formats and legal messages. Examples of protocols include:

- TCP/IP
- HTTP
- SSH

A port is part of socket end point in TCP and UDP. They allow the operating system to distinguish which TCP or UDP service on the host should receive incoming messages.

The confusion generally arises because, a number of ports are reserved (eg. port 80) and are generally listened to by severs expecting a particular protocol (HTTP in the case of port 80). While messages send to port 80 are generally expected to be HTTP messages, there is nothing stopping an non-HTTP server from listening on port 80 or an HTTP server from listening on an alternative port (for example 8080 or 8088).

Comment: That is a confusion))

Comment: U did help a little more:)

Comment: I have been thinking its kind of help for pc processes behind the curtain

Comment: If you find this useful, please upvote. Thanks